# Xamarin Updating and NuGet Cycles

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I'm starting a new project with Xamarin and I'm trying to update everything before I start coding but something weird is happening...

After I update these:
[image]

I get this:
[image]

After I update that, I get the items from the first picture and it just keeps repeating!

What's the deal here and how do I get everything to be updated?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/troubleshooting/):

> Xamarin.Forms is configured to depend on specific versions of the support libraries and Google Play Services. Although the IDE indicates that new versions of the Xamarin.Android.Support packages are available, Xamarin.Forms isn't necessarily compatible with those new versions.

What you're experiencing is expected behavior.

Please check [the NuGet page for Xamarin.Forms](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Forms/) to see the dependencies (and version compatibility).

Comment: Ok... That makes zero sense. 1, how do I know which one I'm actually using then? and 2, how do I handle an actual update?

Comment: You should only update the Xamarin.Forms project in Android. If you update the Android support libraries to their latest version, it will break Xamarin.Forms because the support packages are versions ahead of the required version in the Nuget Package nuspec. You need to uninstall all the packages in the android application and reinstall the most recent Xamarin.Forms package to fix everything. Only update the Xamarin.Forms package in the future and you'll be fine, it will update the support packages to the current supported version.